# Angular 8 ngFor not showing any data from object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this data:

```
var data = {
    id: 1
    version: 1
    user: [
        {
            name: 'paul'
        },
        {
            name: 'peter'
        }
    ],
}
```

And I am trying to display the names by doing this:

```
<ul *ngFor="let dat of data">
  <li>
   {{ dat.user.name }}

  </li>
</ul>
```

But it's not displaying anything.

No errors either...so

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is your data bound to a component in .ts file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to show an array as an object. The for loop cannot access the `.name` property of your `user` property because de `user` property is an array. Try this instead

```
<ul *ngFor="let user of data.user">
  <li>
   {{ user.name }}

  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be running `*ngFor` on the `data.user` which is the list of users:

```
<ul *ngFor="let member of data.user">
```

and display `{{ member.name }}` in the binding